# Woocommerce Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_stock_quantity() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have received a message from WordPress about a fatal error. It relates to a particular page in the backend in the WPML string translation plugin. I think a particular translation:

> visit the page where the error was caught
> (xxxxxxxx/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpml-translation-management%2Fmenu%2Ftranslations-queue.php&return_url=%2Fwp-admin%2Fpost.php%3Fpost%3D117195%26action%3Dedit%26lang%3Den%26message%3D6&job_id=3741&update_needed=1&trid=129987&language_code=fr)

It also says

> Error Details
> ============= An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 259 of the file
> /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/babasouk/functions.php.
> Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
> get_stock_quantity() on null in
> /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php:259
> Stack trace:
> #0 /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): bbloomer_custom_get_availability_text('100 in stock', NULL)
>
> #1 /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-includes/plugin.php(189): WP_Hook->apply_filters('100 in stock', Array)
>
> #2 /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(2082):
> apply_filters('woocommerce_get...', '100 in stock',
> Object(WC_Product_Variation))
>
> #3 /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php(2058):
> WC_Product->get_availability_text()
>
> #4 /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(3512): WC_Product->get_availability()
>
> #5 /nas/content/live/mywebsite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php(367):
> wc_get_stock_html(Object(W

In my PHP I echo get_stock_quantity()and it returns a value. I also tried echo of $product and returned everything. I disabled it because it is too much information.
Website is here. https://babasoukstage.wpengine.com/shop/product-category/decor/moroccan-kilim-pillows/

Could the problem be the '' empty value I am declaring for translation?
__( '', 'babasouk' );

My PHP is

```php
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
  global $product;
  echo wc_get_stock_html( $product );
}
// CHANGE STOCK MESSAGES
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'bbloomer_custom_get_availability_text', 99, 2 );

function bbloomer_custom_get_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
  global $product; // TO MAKE CATEGORY AVAILABLE
  $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity(); //THIS IS LINE 259
    //echo $product; does echo all product details when active
    echo $stock;//test to see if stock quantity returned. Does display on category and product pages.
  // OUTSIDE THE CATEGORY EXCLUSION SO THEY APPLY TO ALL 
  if ( !$product->is_in_stock() )$availability = __( 'Sorry, I am sold out!', 'babasouk' ); //OUT OF STOCK MESSAGE
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() && ( $stock >= 2 ) )$availability = __( '', 'babasouk' ); //NO MESSAGE IF STOCK OVER 1
  //EXCLUDE THESE CATEGORIES FOR 1 ITEM LEFT MESSAGE. IF THESE CATEGORIES MESSAGE IS BLANK.
  if ( has_term( array( 'ORIGINAL ARTWORKS', 'OEUVRES ORIGINALES' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() && ( $stock == 1 ) )$availability = __( '', 'babasouk' ); //
  } //IF NOT EXCLUDED CATEGORIES MESSAGE IS 'Only 1 Available!'
  else if ( $product->is_in_stock() && ( $stock == 1 ) )$availability = __( 'Only 1 Available!', 'babasouk' );
  return $availability;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code and the logs are telling you the issue as well. Since you are in the `functions.php` file, there is no `global $product` available. Because of this you get a null pointer since you overwrite the available product variable with nothing. When I check the snippet on the page you got it from, there is also no `global $product` used - just wondering...

When you check the hook, you can see that there is the product already passed to the function. Just use it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'bbloomer_custom_get_availability_text', 99, 2 );
function bbloomer_custom_get_availability_text( $availability, WC_Product $product ) {
    $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity(); //THIS IS LINE 259
    //echo $product; does echo all product details when active
    error_log( $stock );//test to see if stock quantity returned. Does display on category and product pages.
    // OUTSIDE THE CATEGORY EXCLUSION SO THEY APPLY TO ALL
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        if ( $stock > 1 ) {
            $availability = __( '', 'babasouk' );
        }

        if ( $stock === 1 ) {
            if ( has_term( [ 'ORIGINAL ARTWORKS', 'OEUVRES ORIGINALES' ], 'product_cat', $product ) ) {
                $availability = __( '', 'babasouk' );
            } else {
                $availability = __( 'Only 1 Available!', 'babasouk' );
            }
        }
    } else {
        $availability = __( 'Sorry, I am sold out!', 'babasouk' );
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

I have also improved your code a bit. At the end your function makes not very much sense to me but never mind - just to show you a better way of nesting and speed improvements. If you call a function only once instead multiple times you can improve your page speed.

Comment: Thanks so much. Clearly my PHP skills are limited. Nesting the if statements is so much cleaner than all of my And/Or code. I have one problem though. The "if has term" part does not work. The 2 categories listed still display the "only one available" message. This does work with my messy code. https://babasoukstage.wpengine.com/shop/product-category/art/original-paintings/

Comment: I added some code to echo category names to the page to check my category names are correct.

Comment: As I said - your checks are not making any much sense. I've just changed the nesting accordingly to your code above: I think you still need to overthink your conditions.

Comment: What I want to achieve is this.
A. If a products stock level is 2 or more display nothing.
B. If there is one in stock display "only 1 available" Except if the category is Original Art or OEUVRES ORIGINALES (as there is only ever one and it look stupid).
C. If there are zero in stock display Sorry, I am sold out!
I have to use text domain as the site is bilingual.

Comment: I changed your code from `if ( has_term( [ 'ORIGINAL ARTWORKS', 'OEUVRES ORIGINALES' ], 'product_cat', $product ) ) {` to `if ( has_term( array( 'ORIGINAL ARTWORKS', 'OEUVRES ORIGINALES' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {` and it worked.

Comment: @user9557 Maybe you are running WP on an old PHP version where `[]` is not available. Its shorthand for `array()`. Maybe you should upgrade your PHP version to > 7 since you can get multiple issues because WordPress uses a 7.x.x version as recommendation.

Comment: One point for clarification about what I am doing in the code. I am writing blank __( '', 'babasouk' ) stock messages as the plugin has default stock messages I do not want to display if stock is 2 or higher. I am running on WPEngine on PHP 7.4. So not sure what is wrong, but it works with my change.

Comment: It's not that easy. Some times hosters have older root versions running which causes problems. But if it works for you, all good.

Comment: This works if ( has_term( [ 'ORIGINAL ARTWORKS', 'OEUVRES ORIGINALES' ], 'product_cat' ) ) {

Comment: Your condition can't work because the product is not being passed to the term check. Your check will be always false. Check this: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/if-product-in-category.html

Comment: OK, except it does work. Plus it does not work the other way. The exception excludes the 2 categories from displaying the "only 1 available" message and that message works in all other categories. I thought this would apply but I am guessing. `if( has_term( 4, 'product_cat' ) ) {
 // do something if current product in the loop is in product category with ID 4
}`