# Show message for products that is located in specific category AND has less than 1 quantity in stock - Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, stock

I've been trying to get my mind around what I'm doing wrong for the last two hours. The following code does exactly what I want. If a product has lower than one quantity in stock the message shows as supposed.

The problem, however, is that it doesn't care if the product is located in the category "bomlosa-sadlar" or not. It applies on all products in the whole site.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
/// Show specific message for sadlar
function puri_woocommerce_get_availability_text( $text, $product ) {
    if(!has_term('bomlosa-sadlar', $product->get_id()) AND $product->stock < 1){
      $text = 'Tillverkningsvara, upp till 10 veckors leveranstid';
    }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'puri_woocommerce_get_availability_text', 999, 2);
?>
```

Comment: That's because you're misapplying [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/). 
Also using `$product->stock` seems to be something that would work before WooCommerce 3 (2018), See: [WooCommerce: Get Product Info (ID, SKU, $) From $product Object](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69493785/11987538 
it contains what is stated in your question. (The question I refer to may be different, the answer is almost identical to your question)